# A better way to rearrange a matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a solution to my problem that it is not very graceful nor is it scaleable I would like some help.

I have a matrix which is 50 rows and 30 columns. I want to change it so it is 5 columns and 300 rows. Now that should be easy but I have to move columns 6-10 below 1-5 and then 11-15 etc etc. The code I ended up using was the following

```
fill <- rep(1:20)
m <- matrix(fill, nrow = 50, ncol = 30)

a <-m[,1:5]
b <-m[,6:10]
c <-m[,11:15]
d <-m[,16:20]
e <-m[,21:25]
f <-m[,26:30]

hope <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

How I ended with the original matrix may be the cause of my problem but I have gone a certain track already and would like to tidy up this issue.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(m), 5), function(i) m[,i:(i+4)]))`

Comment: variation thereof: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(m, (col(m) - 1) %/% 5), matrix, ncol = 5))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with matrix subsetting alone by building a vector of the indicies.

```
x <- matrix(m[(1:50+250*rep(0:5,each=50))+50*rep(0:4,each=300)],ncol=5)
all.equal(x,hope)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could divide `m` into a list of matrices and then `rbind` them together using `do.call`. For example,

```
dim(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(1:ncol(m), ceiling(1:ncol(m)/5)), function(i) m[,i])))
#[1] 300   5
```

OR

```
dim(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(m), 5), function(i) m[,i:(i+4)])))
#[1] 300   5
```